# Float doesn't work as expected despite adequate space exist

Tags: html, css, css-float

I created a responsive template from scratch.

Current state of my template is here and (at below of my question): http://jsfiddle.net/w0p9jhbf/

My issue is in `@media screen and (min-width:67em) {...}` where I try to make serious floating actions.

I validated my HTML code, checked for any forgotten R&L margins, decreased the widths of the elements to very low values but I couldn't solve my case.
I also used chrome and ie's inspect element screens but those also didn't help me. CSS validation gives 1 error that is irrelevant to my case. (error about usage of `url(data:image/gif;base64 ...`)

My desired view is:

- nav is vertical on the left (left of screen)
- main part is at the right of nav (middle)
- search box is at the right of main (right of screen)
- aside is at the below of search box (right of screen)

Can you please help me to find what is wrong? No idea comes to my mind after dealing it with ~3 nights.

**important note:** as you can see, I use the code part below to have `border-box`. This code is valid for all responsive states.

```
article,aside,div,form,header,input[type=submit],input[type=text],li,main,nav,section,textarea,ul,footer {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

thanks in advance
best regards

### HTML

Sayfa Başlık
    
    
    
    </script>

```
<header  id="header" role="banner">  
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nw clearfix">
            <li class="current"><a style="border: 0px;" rel="home" href="#" title=""><img  src="http://www.okobe.co.uk/images/scr/P/89/3/1000020389/M01.jpg" alt="logo" /></a></li>
            <li class="di"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/arşiv" title="">Arşiv</a></li>
            <li class="di"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/etiketler" title="">Etiketler</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="hi"><a class="pen" rel="bookmark" href="/yazıya-davet" title="">Sen de!</a></li>
            <li class="di"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/yorumlar" title="">Yorumlar</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="il"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/iletişim" title="">İletişim</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="hk"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/hakkında" title="">Hakkında</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="ht"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/harita" title="">Harita</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <form id="araf1" class="clearfix"  role="search" method="post" action="#">
      <label id="araf1_label" for="araf1_inp">Google ile ara</label>
      <input id="araf1_inp" type="text" name="aranan"  placeholder="Örneğin: Rosa Parks" />
      <input id="araf1_btn" name="aradugme" type="submit" value="Ara">
    </form> 
</header>
<main id="main" role="main" class="clearfix">
    <div id="ana">
        <ul id="#dkr">
            <li class="dd d1">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan introAnahtarları başkalarında olan ve hep öyle kalacak olan kapıların bir bir kapanmakta olduğunu, muradına erme şansının artık tükendiğini idrak eden keloğlanın dramına benziyor bu. Erilemeyen murat, tarihe Muhteşem Falanca diye geçme hayali belli ki.Ama antropolojiden yardım almaksızın sosyolojiye giriş yapmak da zor sanki. İnsanın evrimleşme hızı teknolojinin epeyce gerisinde kalıyor. Uzaktakine sesimizi duyurmak için mikrofonu ağzımıza yaklaştırmak yeterliyken bile, hâlâ dağdan dağa seslenircesine bar bar bağırıyoruz. İstila edercesine çoğalıp yayılan teknolojik imkânlar hayatımızı hangi yönden kolaylaştırdı bilemiyorum ama gittikçe artan bir bağırtı ve kakofoni denizinde boğulduğumuz kesin. Gene de şunca lâfazanlık ve slogan denizini yarıp ortasından geçen bir yol bulmaya, sözü evirip çevirmeden en temel soruyu sorarak meselenin adını koymaya çalışalım:</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d2">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d3">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d4">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d5">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d6">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d1">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
            <li class="dd d2">
                <article>
                    <h1 class="artit">Yazı 1 Başlık</h1>
                    <ul class="aul">
                        <li class="yzn"><a href="#" rel="author">Yazar Ad Soyad</a></li>
                        <li class="trh">26.12.2015</li>
                        <li class="yrm">0 Yorum</li>
                    </ul>               
                    <p class="tntm">tanıtım cümleleri</p>
                    <figure></figure>
                    <p class="intro">yazıdan intro</p>
                    <ul class="ktg clearfix">
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">kategori</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" rel="bookmark">etiket</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="to" href="#" rel="bookmark">Tümünü Oku</a>
                </article>              
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</main>
<aside id="aside">
<h1>ASIDE ASIDE ASIDE</h1>
<p>
ghfdhsjf hdfjdgf djfhsdjfh dhsfd hjdfgd jsfsdj djfj df s sdf jdfdjsdf d hdfsdfgsdj jdfgdjhgd hjgfj gj hdgfjgf jhgsdfjgj jgdhjgf jhfj sdhgfj df fd sd sdfhsf jhdfgjdhjsfdg djgdjf djg jjg djghj sf jhsdfgsdjf jhgdflgu g fdhsgdhf jsf dfgjsdghf jdgsfdf jfjsdgfjgdfh fjsdgfjddygsfj dsjg jdgf djfhsdjfh dhsfd hjdfgd jsfsdj djfj df s sdf jdfdjsdf d hdfsdfgsdj jdfgdjhgd hjgfj gj hdgfjgf jhgsdfjgj jgdhjgf jhfj sdhgfj df fd sd sdfhsf jhdfgjdhjsfdg djgdjf djg jjg djghj sf jhsdfgsdjf jhgdflgu g fdhsgdhf jsf dfgjsdghf jdgsfdf jfjsdgfjgdfh fjsdgfjddygsfj dsjg  jfhsdjfh dhsfd hjdfgd jsfsdj djfj df s sdf jdfdjsdf d hdfsdfgsdj jdfgdjhgd hjgfj gj
</p>
</aside>
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <small>Copyright &copy; <time datetime="2015">2015</time></small>
</footer>

</body>
```

### CSS

```
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary {
    display: block;
}

audio,canvas,progress,video {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

[hidden],template {
    display: none;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:active,a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

mark {
    color: #000;
}

sub,sup {
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
}

sup {
    top: -.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -.25em;
}

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

code,kbd,pre,samp {
    font-family: monospace,monospace;
}

button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    overflow: visible;
}

button,select {
    text-transform: none;
}

button,html input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}

optgroup {
    font-weight: 700;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a:link {
    color: #41b7d8;
}

a:visited {
    color: #41b7d8;
}

a:focus,a:hover {
    color: #e53a2b;
}

a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e53a2b;
}

abbr,address,article,aside,audio,b,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,main,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,p,pre,q,samp,section,small,span,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,ul,var,video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: 0 0;
}

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

article,aside,div,form,header,input[type=submit],input[type=text],li,main,nav,section,textarea,ul,footer {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
    display:inline-block;
}

.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
}

label {
    display: block;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* CUSTOM */

/* font-size:0 resim ile link yüksekliğini aynı yapıyor */
/* display:table-cell olmazsa dikine ortalama yapmıyor*/
.current {
    font-size: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#hk,#il,#ht {
    display: none;
}

.di {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    border-left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dia {
    padding-top: 1.625em;
    padding-bottom: 1.625em;
    display: block;
}

.pen {
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    padding-bottom: .75em;
    display: block;
}

#hi .pen {
    background-image: url(../resimler/ikon/selamlayan-kalem.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
}

.nw a:link,.nw a:visited {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.current:hover,.nw a:focus,.nw a:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    background-color: #ff6;
}

.nw a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e53a2b;
}

#araf1_btn,#araf1_inp {
    border: .08em solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    font-size: .875em;
    line-height: 1.125em;
    height: 2.5em;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    margin: 0;
}

#araf1_inp {
    width: 85%;
    border-top-left-radius: .625em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: .625em;
}

#araf1_btn {
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #e53a2b;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: .625em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .625em;
}

#araf1_label {
    display: none;
}

#araf1, #aside, #main {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.artit {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
}

.tntm,.yzn {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
}

.yzn {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: .08em solid #e5e5e5;
}

.ktg li {
    float: left;
}

/* layout */

#aside,#main,#header,.dd article { overflow:hidden; }

#araf1 {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.dd article,#araf1 {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

.dd article {
    border-bottom: .25em solid #41b7d8;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

#aside,#footer {
    padding: 2em 2%;
}

/* viewport */

@media screen and (min-width:26em) {

    #il {display:block;}
    .di {width:20%;}

}
@media screen and (min-width:29em) {

    #hk {display:block;}
    .di {width:16.66667%;}

}
@media screen and (min-width:31em) {

    #ht {display:block;}
    .di {width:14.28571%;}

}
@media screen and (min-width:37em) {

    #araf1 {
        position: relative;
        left: 54%;
        bottom: 8em;
        width: 45%;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #main {
        margin-top: -2.1875em; /* height of search form */   
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width:48em) {

    .dd {
        padding-left:10%;
        border-left-width: .625em;
        border-left-style: solid;
    }
    .d1 { border-left-color: #c9e9e5; }
    .d2 { border-left-color: #cdeeaa; }
    .d3 { border-left-color: #f9f0a8; }
    .d4 { border-left-color: #e0cfdf; }
    .d5 { border-left-color: #faced2; }
    .d6 { border-left-color: #bcd8f0; }
    .dd article {
        padding-left: 0%;
        padding-right: 8%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:67em) {
    .dd {
        padding-left:0;
        border-left-width: 0;

    }
    .dd article {
        padding-left: 2em;      
        padding-right: 1.5em;
    }
    .current,.di {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width:12em;
        line-height:1em;
        border:0;
    }
    .current {
        font-size:1em;
        border-bottom:.0625em solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        padding-top:1em;
        padding-bottom:1em;
        background-color:#fff;
        border-top-left-radius:.625em;
    }
    .di {
        border-bottom:.0625em solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        border-right:.0625em solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        text-align:left;
    }

    .dia {
        padding: 1.5em 0 1.5em 4em;
    }   

    .pen {
        padding: 1.5em 1em 1.5em 2em;
    }
    #nav {
        width: 12em;
    }

    #araf1 {
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        margin-top:3em;
    }
    #main {
        margin-top:0;       
        padding-bottom:2em;
    }
    #main,#nav {
        float: left;
        margin-top: .625em;
    }
    #main {
        width: 58%;
        padding-top: 2.8125em;
        border-radius: 0 .625em .625em;
    }

    #araf1,#aside {
        float: right;
        width: 42%;
        margin-left: -12em;
        padding-left: 13em;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding-right: .5%;
    }

    #araf1_label {
        display: block;
    }
    #footer {        
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:70em) {
    .dd {
        padding-left:5%;
        border-left-width: .625em;
        border-left-style: solid;   
    }
    .dd article {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top:0;
        padding-right:5%;
    }
    #ana {
        padding-top:2.4375em;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:80em) {
    .dd {
        padding-left:8%;    
    }
    .dd article {
        padding-right:8%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:90em) {
    .dd {
        padding-left:10%;   
    }
    .dd article {
        padding-right:10%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:100em) {
    #araf1,#aside {        
        padding-left: 15em;
        padding-right: 1.5%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please shorten your code? In particular it was completely unnecessary to include an entire data URI in your question.

Comment: I tried to shorten however I destructed the structural integrity. and I tried to simulate however I couldn't.Let me try again but I hope jsfiddle link make question solvers' thinking easier. sorry for long code.thanks for comment

Comment: The fiddle code should stay put, but it was not necessary to include all of the code from the fiddle into the question here, because I'm sure not all of it is essential to the problem at hand. Besides the data URI example, we don't really need to know that you're using normalize.css either. That's a *lot* of lines that can be shaved.

Comment: Deleting one by one, I worked this line: `#aside,#main,#header,.dd article { overflow:hidden; }` and found that only `#header` creates all fuzz. For now I solved my case however couldn't understand why? this'll be another question that I should ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after deleting `#header` from `#aside,#main,#header,.dd article { overflow:hidden; }` case has been solved.

I couldn't understand why this action solved my case.

maybe the possible reasons are:

1. floating block level elements (`#nav` and `#araf1`) in `#header` already have `.clearfix`
2. I float `#nav` to left and `#araf1` to right so maybe overflow shouldn't be hidden.

as I've said, I solved 'what' but couldn't get 'why'.
Best regards

```
<header  id="header" role="banner">  
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nw clearfix">
            <li class="current"><a style="border: 0px;" rel="home" href="#" title=""><img  src="http://www.okobe.co.uk/images/scr/P/89/3/1000020389/M01.jpg" alt="logo" /></a></li>
            <li class="di"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/arşiv" title="">Arşiv</a></li>
            <li class="di"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/etiketler" title="">Etiketler</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="hi"><a class="pen" rel="bookmark" href="/yazıya-davet" title="">Sen de!</a></li>
            <li class="di"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/yorumlar" title="">Yorumlar</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="il"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/iletişim" title="">İletişim</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="hk"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/hakkında" title="">Hakkında</a></li>
            <li class="di" id="ht"><a class="dia" rel="bookmark" href="/harita" title="">Harita</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <form id="araf1" class="clearfix"  role="search" method="post" action="#">
      <label id="araf1_label" for="araf1_inp">Google ile ara</label>
      <input id="araf1_inp" type="text" name="aranan"  placeholder="Örneğin: Rosa Parks" />
      <input id="araf1_btn" name="aradugme" type="submit" value="Ara">
    </form> 
</header>
```

Comment: I asked "why", at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982735/in-which-cases-applying-overflowhidden-destructs-floating-as-the-only-reaso